# 丸数字、例えば ㉙ が閲覧時に文字化けするのは、どういう条件が揃ったときですか？

Tags: 文字化け, 文字コード

丸数字、例えば ㉙ が閲覧時に文字化けするのは、どういう条件が揃ったときですか？

Comment: 何か実際に問題があったのでしょうか？ あるいは何かのテストケースを考えるうえでどんな可能性があるか聞いてみたといったようなことでしょうか？ 前者ならもっと具体的な状況などの情報を記述した方が良いでしょうし、後者で今の記述程度の内容ならこのサイトでは避けた方がよい質問の部類になってしまうのでは？ [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 「機種依存文字」はこれまで何も考えず一律に除外していたのですが、とあるケースで円の中にアラビア数字が使用されていて、なおかつ厳密な対応を求められなかった(一部の例外は無視してOKみたいな感じでした)ので、文字化けする可能性があるケースとしては実際にどんな条件が揃ったときか知りたく質問しました。

Comment: 元の質問は「機種依存文字」の話で、それを誰かが勝手に「丸数字」の話に書き換えた。そして回答は「〇に２９という文字」に限った話になっている。勝手に質問を書き換えるのがここの流儀らしいけど、こういうのはダメだよね。

Comment: いやそれなら**あなたが**「機種依存文字」に対する回答書けばよいのですよ。文句ぶーぶー言う前に。「機種依存文字」なる２１世紀においては読者間での合意が得られそうにないあいまいな文言に対して回答するのはオイラには無理なので〇に２９限定にしたのに、そこを文句言われても知らんっス。

Comment: 774RR さんに文句を言ってるわけではありません。元の質問を書き換えること、それが許されていることが疑問だと言っておるのです。

Comment: "いやそれなら**あなたが**「機種依存文字」に対する回答書けばよいのですよ"・・・とのことですけど、今の質問 "丸数字、例えば ㉙ が閲覧時に文字化けするのは、どういう条件が揃ったときですか？" にそういうことを書いても、閲覧者は ???? って感じなのでは？

Comment: @WebSurfer このサイトの編集の機能に関しては[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)を確認し、良くない編集と思った場合はご自分で修正した編集を提案してください(提案は誰でもできます)。このサイトの編集の機能そのものに対して意見がある場合は[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)に質問を投稿してください。コメントは機能に関して議論する場所ではありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

今話題にしたい〇に２９という文字は `U+3259` であるとして。 Web 系に話を限定。

読者側に文字化けの原因がある例

- 文字セットに当該文字が存在しないとき

世の中には UNICODE を採用していない環境、ないしは UNICODE を扱えても故意に他の文字セットに話を限定する機能があったりします。

JIS X 0208 には〇に数値という文字は採用されていません。つまり純粋に JIS X 0208 にある文字のみ扱う環境では〇に数値の文字は表記できません。俗にいう `NEC PC98 文字セット` には〇に１から２０までの文字が採用されましたが２１以上は採用されていません。 Microsoft コードページ 932 においても同様です。

このような環境においては〇に２９なる文字はそもそも表現方法がありません。そういう場所に外部から `U+3259` なる文字を導入しようとすると、当該環境内部においては表現方法が無いのだから別の文字に置き換えるしかありません＝違う文字になる＝文字化けします。

例：現代 Windows (NT/2000 系列) においては Windows 内部で扱うコードが UNICODE で `UTF-16` エンコードを使うという仕様です。なので **Windows 自体は** 〇に２９を取り扱うことができます。しかしあえて `MBCS` な日本語 Win32 アプリケーションを作れば、その内部では CP932 で文字を表現しますので〇に２９を表現できません。違う文字に置き換えられたり、そもそも削除されてしまったりします。

・文字フォントにグリフが無い場合

UNICODE 対応をうたう環境下でフォントセット中に当該グリフが無いってのはレアだと思われますが皆無でもないでしょう。あるフォントセット中にグリフが無い文字は違うフォントセットのグリフで代用されたりするので見た目が化けることもありそうです。

記述者側に原因がある例

・ `<META>` 中の文字セット（というかエンコーディング）指定と本文が異なる

本文が `UTF-8` なのに誤って `<META charset="Shift_JIS">` と書いた場合などには文字化けするでしょう。ただしこの場合は全部の文字が化けて見えるはず（特定１文字だけ化けることは考えられない）

ということで２０２４年の現時点では一般人が普通に使う Web UA では特定文字だけの文字化けは故意に起こそうとしない限り起きないと思われます。